# Mobile, better_errors, Facebook app and localhost/.local?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, mobile, localhost, better-errors-gem

This is a question about how to set up my Rails development environment.

I want to do three things which seem incompatible:

- Test on my laptop and iPhone at the same time, meaning macbookmihai.local:3000
- Use better_errors, meaning localhost:3000
- Require Omniauth with Facebook, so only one of the two can be whitelisted in my FB app

I've read the "TRUSTED_IP" hack on the better_errors front page, but I don't fully understand it (and wouldn't my IP change every time?)

Is there a solution to my dilemma?

Comment: Obivously... I can go to the FB app each time I want to test the mobile view, or I can give up better_errors.  But I'd like to have my cake and eat it too.

Comment: you could disable IP checking entirely for the course of development. You obviously can't deploy your app to production like that (open it to world). Does such solution interest you?

Comment: Also, do you need to see better_errors on the iphone?